# How do I prevent the inputToolbar from being hidden by the keyboard (JSQMessagesViewControlelr)?

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

When I tap the textfield to type my message in JSQMessagesViewController, the keyboard moves up and blocks the input textfield. How do I fix this? There is also this error which pops up if I type something after:                                -[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on > without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation.

Comment: just move you view up when keyboard is appearing.

Comment: Yes, but normally, when I use JSQMessageViewController the toolbar moves up automatically. Do you have any idea as to why this could not be working?

Comment: is the view inheriting form `JSQMessagesViewController` or are you adding it as a subview.

Comment: Probably very old but if you nest JSQMessagesViewController then the keyboard events don't trigger